# Two proof by ϵ−δ definition

Tags: calculus, continuity

$$(1.)\text{ }f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
sin(x), &\text{ }x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
cos(x), &\text{ }x\notin \Bbb{Q}
\end{cases}
,\text{ prove that f is continuous at x = }\cfrac{\pi}{4}\text{ }by\text{ }\epsilon-\delta \text{ } \text{definition}$$

$$(2.)\text{ }f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^2, &\text{ }x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
x^3, &\text{ }x\notin \Bbb{Q}
\end{cases}
,\text{ prove that f is differentiable at x = 0}\text{ }by\text{ }\epsilon-\delta \text{ }  \text{definition}$$

I know I have to prove $\lim_{x\to \cfrac{\pi}{4}}$ f(x) = f($\cfrac{\pi}{4}$) in problem 1 and $\lim_{h\to 0} \cfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ exists in problem 2. But I don't know how to use ϵ−δ definition in these problems. Also, what should I do in such problems that the value of f(x) is given based on if the value of x is rational number or not. Any suggestion or hint is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may want to try invoking the Archimedian property of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: HINT: $\sin(\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4)$ and $0^2=0^3$. USe $\delta$· of each part of each function and take minimum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLAIM: Let $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ be continuous functions at a point $a\in\Bbb R$ such that $h(a)=g(a)$. The the function $$f(x):=\begin{cases}h(x)& x\in\Bbb Q\\ g(x)&x\notin\Bbb Q\end{cases}$$ is continuous at $a$.

PROOF:

Observe that no matter if $a$ is rational or not, $f(a)=g(a)=h(a)$ is uniquely defined.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$.

AS $g(x)$ is continuous in $a$, there is $\delta_g>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta_g$ then $|g(x)-g(a)|<\varepsilon$.

AS $h(x)$ is continuous in $a$, there is $\delta_h>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta_g$ then $|h(x)-h(a)|<\varepsilon$.

Take $\delta:=\min(\delta_g,\delta_h)>0$ and observe that $\delta<\delta_g$ and $\delta<\delta_h$.

Take $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$

- If $x\in\Bbb Q$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|=|h(x)-h(a)|<\varepsilon$, since $|x-a|<\delta<\delta_h$.
- If $x\notin\Bbb Q$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|=|g(x)-g(a)|<\varepsilon$, since $|x-a|<\delta<\delta_g$.

So, in both cases $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$ and $f$ is continuous at $a$.

---

You can apply this same $\varepsilon-\delta$ argument to both problems:

(1) $h(x)=\sin x$, $g(x)=\cos x$ and $a=\pi/4$.

(2) $h(x)=x^2$, $g(x)=x^3$ and $x=0$ for continuity and $h(x)=2x$, $g(x)=3x^2$ $a=0$ for derivability.

Comment: Thank you! I got it. But in question 2, I needs to prove it is differentiable at x = 0. Is the proof still suitable to prove it?

Comment: Differentiate each part and apply the same result (with $h(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=3x^2$.